VBA WORD. Как вставить перевод курсора перед и после таблицы?
Перед и после второй таблицы в документе нужно что-бы было 2 пустых строки.
   Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
   tbl.Range.Select
   Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
   Selection.InsertBefore Text:=vbCrLf & vbCrLf
   tbl.Range.Select
   Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
   Selection.InsertAfter Text:=vbCrLf & vbCrLf

Только один с переводов каретки, которые должны быть перед таблицей, почему-то помещается в первую ячейку первой строки. Как исправить?

Помещаете курсор в начало самой первой (левой верхней) ячейки таблицы и выполняете Selection.SplitTable. После чего добавляете в текущее местоположение ещё один перевод строки.

tbl.cell(1, 1).Range.Collapse wdCollapseStart;Selection.SplitTable добавляет перевод строки перед таблицей, но только сбрасывается на дефолтный шрифт и параметры в месте разрыва, которые не соотвествуют шрифту и параметрам всего текста что визуально отличаетсся

но только сбрасывается на дефолтный шрифт и параметры в месте разрыва, которые не соотвествуют шрифту и параметрам всего текста что визуально отличаетсся Ну присвойте нужный стиль... или скопируйте формат. Ну или так - опять же ставим курсор в начало таблицы, а потом Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1 : Selection.TypeParagraph : Selection.TypeParagraph. Тогда сохранится стиль того абзаца, что перед таблицей.
